# What is correct approach for multiple asynchronous data sending?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm designing a web page that uses lots of real-time graphs per page. But there won't be more than 10-15 active users. 
Each page can have its own refresh interval. Data is sending with WebSockets using Socket.IO on the server-side.
My first approach is on page load client js will look for graph elements. Details about the graph are stored in HTML data- attribute. The client will send graphs with their attributes to the Node.JS server. My problem is how should I create asynchronous functions on the server-side to send data back to clients. 
Edit: Just an example of what I am trying to do. For example, if page-1 has 4 different graphs and page-2 another 5 different graphs I don't want to send data to each page for 9 graphs each time. I want to send data separately. Send only 4 graph data to page-1 with 2000ms interval and 5 graph data to page-2 with 10000ms interval.

Here is my current approach. To make it simple I'm assuming there is just one graph per page.

```
server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    var charts = socket.handshake.query.charts;
    console.log("client connected with: " + charts);
    users.push(socket);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        users.splice(users.indexOf(socket), 1);
    });
});
```

Which simply stores active clients.

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  for(var i = 0; i<users.length; i++){
      users[i].emit('test', 'data');    
      console.log("data sent to: " + users[i].id);
  }
}


var charts = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("live-chart");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var content = elements[i].getAttribute('data-content');
    var type = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
    var interval = elements[i].getAttribute('data-interval');
    var chart = {content: content, type:type, interval: interval};
    charts.push(chart);
}
var socket = io.connect("http://step.demo:3000", { query: "charts=" + JSON.stringify(charts) });
```

This client code sends the server which graphs the current page has.
Sample server side output.

```
client connected with: [{"content":"machine","type":"line","interval":"1000"}]
```

I stuck at how can I create lots of asynchronous functions according to each client's refresh setting and then stop them at the disconnect event. Or maybe is there another way of doing this like adding CRON jobs in but with much shorter intervals.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're asking for help with or what problem you're trying to solve.  Your current code sends an update to each currently connected client every second. What is your problem with that?  FYI, you don't have to manually keep track of every connection and manually iterate through  them.  `io.emit()` will send to all currently connected clients for you.  That functionality already exists inside of the server-side socket.io library with `io.emit()` where `io` is the server-side instance of socket.io.

Comment: `io.emit()` will send all data to all clients. I want to send only the needed data for that page. For example if current page has 4 different graphs and other page another 5 different graph I dont want to send data for 9 graph each time. I want to send data separately.

Comment: Well, then you either need to have the page request the data it wants and you can then respond with that data or you have to have the client tell you which graphs it wants and you store that and send only that data to it on the next interval.  There's nowhere in your question that I could see that is what you're asking for because your current code snippet just sends the same data to all clients which is why I suggested `io.emit()`.  I still don't know what you want us to help with.  Please edit your question to clarify what you want help with.

Comment: FYI, all networking in node.js is asynchronous so you don't need to "create lots of asynchronous functions".  You just do networking and it's naturally asynchronous.

Comment: Sorry, I was too excited about and forget some code blocks. I added them to main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to send different data to different clients, then somewhere along the line your server needs to know which data goes to which clients and the server needs to store that so at the next interval, it can look up what data goes to clientA and send only its data and what data goes to clientB and send only that data.

I have no idea how your pages are initialized or how the graphs are initialized to know what all the options are.  Absent any of that info, the simplest way would be for the client to just send the server a message that tells the server which graphs it wants data on and the server can then store that right on the client-side socket object.

Then, when you go to send data to that client, you can look at the custom property on its  socket object that lists what graphs it wants and only send those graphs.

Since, it appears you're sending graphs as a query parameter upon connection, you could capture that info at connection time.

```
server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    try {
         socket._charts = JSON.parse(socket.handshake.query.charts);
         console.log("client connected with: " + socket._charts);
         users.push(socket);
    } catch(err) {
         console.log(err);
    }
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        users.splice(users.indexOf(socket), 1);
    });
});
```

Then, whenever you are iterating through your sockets, to send them updated data, you can access `socket._charts` to see which charts it wants data for.

---

If what you're trying to do is to start a new interval timer for every new connection (which I have no idea why you would do it that way), you can do this:

```
server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    let interval;
    try {
         let charts = JSON.parse(socket.handshake.query.charts);
         console.log("client connected with: " + charts);
         users.push(socket);
         interval = setInterval(() => {
             // interval timer for each separate socket
             // process your interval here using the charts variable
             socket.emit(...);    // send data to just the one socket in this interval
         }, 1000);
    } catch(err) {
         console.log(err);
    }
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        users.splice(users.indexOf(socket), 1);
        clearInterval(interval);                 // stop timer for this socket
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually this is what I am trying to do. Lets assume my socket object has a custom property which contains graph details and intervals. When I create a function with setInterval, even if socket disconnects, server tries to send data to it. I should store these setInterval functions with socket relationships and stop them at disconnect.

Comment: @kenarsuleyman - The server won't try to send data to a socket that has disconnected because you will have removed it from the array.  Why do you think you want a separate interval for each socket?  That's less efficient that one interval that updates all the currently connected sockets.

Comment: Inside a main loop Iterating all clients with a fixed interval and sending data to them is a solution and easy to implement. But what I am trying to do each socket will have it's own interval. To do that I am creating a setInterval function  according to socket object. With this approach even if socket disconnects, setInterval function still runs.

Comment: @kenarsuleyman - Sorry, but that makes no sense to me.  Why do you want the interval to continue when the socket has disconnected.  That sounds like a waste of server resources since that interval has nothing to do (the client is disconnected).  In fact, if you do this then when that client comes back to your site some future time, you'll start yet another interval for it and over time your number of intervals will go up and up and up, wasting more and more server CPU.

Comment: That's why I am looking for a way to stop/clear all intervals client has on disconnect.

Comment: @kenarsuleyman - OK, I don't get why/what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want to start a socket-specific interval timer for each socket when it connects, just start it in the `connection` event and stop it in the `disconnect` event.  You can just store the timerID in a local variable in the `connection` callback and you then access that same variable from the `disconnect` event.

Comment: @kenarsuleyman - More code added to the answer about a separate timer for each socket.